# How to automatically show Progress Bar on each retrofit API call?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, retrofit2

How to achieve showing a progress bar on each `Retrofit 2.0` API call without having to make a progress bar in each activity, showing it and dismissing. Progress bar should show **whenever** an API is hit and it should dismiss when we get a response on `onResponse` or `onFailure` is called.

I tried this :

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mProgressDialog.show();
retrofitService.login(new SignInRequest(email, password),
                new Callback<SignInResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<SignInResponse> call, Response<SignInResponse> response) {

              if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
          }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<SignInResponse> call, Throwable t) {
              if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
          }
 });
```

But this code will have to copy pasted everywhere whenever I make an API call. I don;t want duplicate code.

Comment: make a  base activity to do all this work?

Comment: Please provide an example..

Comment: use base callback or interceptor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by @Sourabh, I ended up using a Base activity and calling simple method during each API call. In `BaseActivity`,

```
public void showDialog() {

    if(mProgressDialog != null && !mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideDialog() {

    if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

In your child activity, you can directly call `showDialog()` and `hideDialog()` to show and dismiss dialog.

Answer (score 12):

A base class for your callbacks can be handy.

```
class BaseCallBack implements CallBacks<T>{
  @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

          if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
              mProgressDialog.dismiss();
      }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<SignInResponse> call, Throwable t) {
          if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
              mProgressDialog.dismiss();
      }
}
```

When you send a request:

```
retrofitService.login(new SignInRequest(email, password), new MyCallback<SignInResponse>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<SignInResponse> call, Response<SignInResponse> response) {
          super.onResponse(call, response);
          //do more on response
      }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<SignInResponse> call, Throwable t) {
          super.onFailure(call, t);
          /* Do more on failure. For example: give a reason why the
           request failed*/ 
      }
 });
```

Edit 2019 - using the RXjava adapter:

```
   getUsers()
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.io()) //run request in the background and deliver response to the main thread aka UI thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> showLoading())
        .doOnTerminate(() -> hideLoading())
        .subscribe(data -> {
            //request is successful
        }, error -> {
            //show error
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answers of Shubham and peter, I wrote a class like this:

```
class CustomCallBack<T> implements Callback<T> {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
Context context;

CustomCallBack(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    ((Activity) context).getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }

}
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Shameless Promotion</sub>

I've created [RxLoading library](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading) for that, it can do this and much more,

you can just do something like this:

```
networkCall().compose(RxLoading.<>create(loadingLayout)).subscribe(...);
```

it consists out of 2 classes, a custom view (loadingLayout) and RxLoading which is a [transformer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#transformational-operators) that glue it all together, you can choose to work with both or either of them.

If you want one progress bar to rule them all, you have several options to achieve it depending on the structure of your app:

- one Activity multiple fragments -> just put a loadingLayout in the main screen and tell it to hide the fragment layout when loading
- multiple activities: create a base activity which all uses and inject a loadingLayout to all of you views
- you can also make a special dialog or activity for the progress bar and use an interface for RxLoading to show and hide it.

RxLoading also supports empty and error states (with built-in retry mechanism, so make sure to check this options as well)

you can find out more on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading).

Answer (score 1):

**Example from tutorial:**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    ArrayAdapter<Question> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new ArrayList<Question>());
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);
}
```

Tutorial link:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: This approach is deprecated since API 21. Is there any alternative for Rx?